# How to remove the sql injection from this query and make it working well?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-injection

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I am developing a web-based application in which there is a menu bar that has many options. Some of these options will be displayed only to the Admin. There is a logic behind the system to check whether the user is an admin or not. If yes, the options will be displayed. I wrote the method but I have a sql injectiom and I want to remove it.

For your information, I have the following database design:

- **Users** table: `NetID, Name, Title`
- **Admins** table: `ID, NetID`

Here's the C# method:

```
private bool isAdmin(string username)
{
        string connString = "Data Source=appSever\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True";
        string cmdText = "SELECT ID, NetID FROM dbo.Admins WHERE NetID = '" + NetID + "')";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            // Open DB connection.
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader != null)
                    if (reader.Read())
                        if (reader["ID"].Equals(1))
                            return true;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to change it by doing the changing the third line to:

```
string cmdText = "SELECT ID, NetID FROM dbo.Admins WHERE NetID = @NetID)";
```

But I got the following error and I don't know why:

> *Must declare the scalar variable "@NetID".*

**Could you please help me in solving this?**

****UPDATE:**

```
After updating the code to the following:
    private bool isAdmin(string username)
    {
        string NetID = username;
        string connString = "Data Source=appServer\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True";
        string cmdText = "SELECT ID, NetID FROM dbo.Admins WHERE NetID = @NetID";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            // Open DB connection.
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NetID", NetID);
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader != null)
                    if (reader.Read())
                        if (reader["NetID"] == username)
                            return true;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I got the following error:

***Incorrect syntax near ')'.***

**How to fix this problem?**

Comment: You might also consider SQL Stored Procedures.

Comment: Fixed your problem, see my edit :) +1 for removing SQL injection ;)

Comment: I am still facing the same problem and getting that error with the following: 'SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();'

Comment: there was a stray ")" at the end of the cmdText string, I removed it in your code sample below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 private bool isAdmin(string username)
 {
    string connString = "Data Source=appSever\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True";
    string cmdText = "SELECT ID, NetID FROM dbo.Admins WHERE NetID = @NetID)";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        // Open DB connection.
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NetID", NetID);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader != null)
                if (reader.Read())
                    if (reader["ID"].Equals(1))
                        return true;
            return false;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. I think I have a mistake in the logic. Because as you see in my database design in the question NetID is a foreign key from Admins Table to Users Table so I think I should read NetID column not ID, right? Could you please help me with this?

Comment: What is saved in Id and NetId columns?

Comment: ID is an auto-incremented primary key. NetID is the username of the user which is a foreign key to the primary key in the Users Table

Answer (score 8):

You need to pass a value for your `@NetID` parameter:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NetID", NetID);
```

Comment: @TechnologyLover, I've compiled the updated code and did not receive any error. Use `whosrdaddy` edited the code and fixed the error. If you need more help on this project please let me know. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

If you use NetId as parameter in the IsAdmin method than it would help

```
 private bool isAdmin(string NetID)
{
string connString = "Data Source=appSever\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True";
 string cmdText = "SELECT ID, NetID FROM dbo.Admins WHERE NetID = @NetID)";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();
    // Open DB connection.
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NetID", NetID);
        string value = cmd.ExecuteScalar().tostring();
        if (value != null)
           return true;
       else
           return false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@netid",SqlBdType.Int).Value=NetID;
```